# Using Id in select clauses

Tags: apex, soql, id

I have the next code:

---

```
 for (User U: newUsersData)
      {

            .............


              List <employee__c> LEmp =  [select   ID, 
                                  Email__c,
                                First_Name__c,
                                Last_Name__c,
                                User_Record__c,
                                Title__c,
                                MSC__c,
                                Global_Department__c

                                          from employee__c 
                                          where User_Record__c = :U.Id                                                        
                                   ];

               ....
```

---

User_Record__c is a lookup over User. The object  employee__c   has User_Record__c  as a field. Whenever I run the previous Select query LEmp becomes empty. But, if I write at the query console:

```
select   ID, Email__c, First_Name__c,
         Last_Name__c,  User_Record__c,
         Title__c,  MSC__c, Global_Department__c
 from employee__c 
 where User_Record__c = :'SOMEUSERID'
```

where SOMEUSERID  represents the ID of the user I am looking for then I get the row I need. 
Is there something wrong with my syntax?
Thanks

Comment: Your syntax is fine if your code compiles. Check the value of `U.Id` - it may be set to a value for which there are no related `employee__c` records.

Comment: You also need to remove SOQL from the for loop. You can capture all userIds in set and then query on Employee Object using IN operator.

Comment: I have a   system.debug(U.id )   command executing just before the query and it shows the id of the user I am looking for. The code compiles. I might have to "recapture" the id in another variable.... hmmm

Comment: I must mention that this code is being executed in test mode. So, the employee__c table might not be visible. We tried executing a query like  [select Id from employee__c] instead and an empty list for LEmp was returned. Could this be also permissions? If this is the case, which ones could be?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga - If you are running the code in test mode you have to populate the records prior to testing your code. By default, existing data is isolated and not visible to during test methods.